# Web.config configuration seems correct. But still can't access database on the hosting server

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, asp.net-mvc-3, web-config

I know there is a high possibility of this question being asked by many people. but I'm very confident that I have read most of those questions and still wasn't able to find solution.

below are all the steps I have done so far in details in order to deploy my web application on the Godaddy hosting servers:

- I am using ASP.NET MVC 3 (C#).
- I have uploaded and deployed the website on godaddy hosting services.
- I have inserted my database by executing the Script I generated from my SSMS into the godaddy MS SQL server database.

Finally, according to [this](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/3323/locating-your-database-connection-strings) I was able to get my connectionString.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>

  <connectionStrings>
  <add name="database-name" connectionString="Data Source=mysource; Initial Catalog=database-name; User ID=userid; Password=password;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

However, I'm still not able to connect my web application to its database when I try it on the internet. I'm very sure that my connectionString is correct since it's been just copy-pasted from my host service provider.

I am pretty sure I have missed something except my webconfig or my connectionString. Is there anything else except web.config file that is critical and has effects on connection?

Regards,
Amin

EDIT:

Sorry to not mention earlier. I DID put the correct "name", "Data Source", "Data Source", "User ID" and "Password".
I intentionally changed them for security purposes.

SECOND EDIT:

There is no error when I try to fetch the data in my application.. the response is just simply null from the database. But my tables DOES exist in the database with all the data inside.

Comment: just to check, you DID change the username password combination to your credentials right? :) User ID=userid; Password=password;

Comment: @user1807954 You should mention the exception message.

Comment: When you provide no informations, how are we supposed to help you? Provide an exception message, tell us what database framework you're using, what kind of database server do you use?

Comment: Are you sure your web.config file isn't undergoing build configuration transformation when you deploy under a different mode e.g. release?

Comment: Can you in any way connect to the database after you deployed it? If so, how? Are you getting any errors? If so, please provide a stack trace.

Comment: @Bablo I have removed the "debug=true" part, but still can't connect.

Comment: @Jocke I cannot connect to it in any way. If it helps, since I'm using AJAX call in one of my pages, when I checked the response in firebug it's just empty and it doesn't give any error.

Comment: Sounds like your application is eating the exceptions that are occurring. There is no way the database will fail and not return an exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the Database instance accept http traffic? Can you locate and connect to it from e.g. SQL Management Studio?

Comment: the website has not yet gone live. But there is a Preview button where you can check your website before put it live on internet. About the direct access to the database, I have not enabled that option when I created the database in the hosting server for more security purposes.

Comment: But can you explain more what does it mean if I won't be able to connect to it from SSMS? (after I enabled the direct access option). Thank you.

Comment: That you have to make the correct configuration on the database instance, and that your web.config can still be valid.